# Rails - Pass variable in flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I've been trying to add a variable in the flash notice that appears when post been created with `#{variable}`

But I must be missing something because the only message I receive is "#{variable}".

This is my controller:

```
 def create

    @participant = Participant.new(params[:participant])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        mail = params[:email]
        format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Thanks, We will be sending out instructions to:  #{mail}' }
        format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've been trying with @participants as variable aswell, but still, I don't get anything but the actual "#{@participants}" in the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your filling the mail in the participant form so try with:

```
   email = params[:participant][:mail]
```

and write it with `""` instead of `''`

Comment: Yeah, it was the "" instead of ''---- =) Thanks

Comment: No problem, is that it? Glad i could help :)

Comment: Yeah it was =) And just params[:email] didn't work but @participants.email did =)

Comment: Yeah, i was going to write it also in my solution, but i guessed that wasn't the main problem :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the string with double quotes instead of single quotes.

[Double quotes actually allow string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Double_quotes). Which is what you want here.

So write:

```
format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: "Thanks, We will be sending out instructions to:  #{mail}" }
```

Comment: Yes, I was know that it only can be done with `double quotes` but I still don't know the reason, and thank for your help that really help me figured it out!

Comment: Is interpolating like that a security risk?